# How to test a condition in a sql case statement on numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to substitute all the values that are greater or equal to 10 with an empty string with a SQL CASE statement on my Microsoft SQL Server 2017. However, I am getting an error that reads:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Though there are some questions similar to my question, I can not find an answer that is specifically answering my question. For example this question here [how to use > = condition in sql case statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165400/how-to-use-condition-in-sql-case-statement). I have also tried a dynamic query with a temporal table and this did not help.

Here is my code with the table definition and the test data as well as the actual query that I am running.

```
--table definition with two columns
declare @table table 
               (
                    person nvarchar(20),
                    digit decimal(10,2)
               )

--insert test data with two records
insert into @table
    select 'titimo', 9.51
    union 
    select 'neriwo', 12.25

--the requirement is to not show the digit value if it is greater or equal to 10, but rather display an empty field.
--so, this is my select statement to meet this requirement that is failing 
--with error message 'Incorrect syntax near >'
select
    person,
    case digit
        when digit >= 10 then ''
        else digit
    end 'digit'
from @table
```

From my select statement above, I am expecting this output:

```
person digit
------ -----
titimo 9.51
neriwo
```

However, the output is not being generated because of the error message that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a syntax error in your `case`. More over you cannot mix datatypes so you need to cast `digit` to `varchar` or change `''` i.e. to `null`.

```
select
    person,
    case 
        when digit >= 10  then ''
        else cast(digit as varchar(20))
    end 'digit'
from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

Your case is not formatted correctly - here's one option -
(also, you can't select text and numbers in the same column - so I casted your number to text... tweak to fit your needs)

```
select
    person,
    case when digit >=10 then ''
        else CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), digit)
    end 'digit'
from @table
```

Comment: Thank you @FizzBuzz. Your answer and explanation is the same as M. Kanarkowsk   above. I will accept your answer as well.

Comment: Only this was answered first :)